# How to Flutter Background Image Positioning

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

When I write the Background Image codes in the main.dart file that I shared with you below, the data I want to use remains under Image. How can I solve this problem? I am aware that I wrote the part about Background in the wrong place, but I didn't know where to write it. Thank you for your help.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Weather App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Weather App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            //WEATHER DATA
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: weatherData != null
                        ? Weather(weather: weatherData)
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: isLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 2.0,
                            valueColor:
                                new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.black),
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                            tooltip: 'Refresh',
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await loadWeather();
                            },
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            //BACKGROUND IMAGE
            Container(
              height: 501.7,
              width: 420.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: isweatherDataLoaded //this
                      ? HandleError()
                      : images["clear"],
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
            ),

            //FUTURE FORECAST WEATHER DATA
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: forecastData != null
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: forecastData.list.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => WeatherItem(
                              weather: forecastData.list.elementAt(index)))
                      : Container(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]))),
    );
  }
```

Wherever I write, it just didn't work. I want you to show me a way. If you want, I can share the rest of my codes with you. Happy Codding! Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest moving the container with the background image up in the hierarchy, like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Weather App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Weather App'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            height: 501.7,
            width: 420.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: isweatherDataLoaded //this
                    ? HandleError()
                    : images["clear"],
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  //WEATHER DATA
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: weatherData != null
                              ? Weather(weather: weatherData)
                              : Container(),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: isLoading
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 2.0,
                            valueColor:
                            new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.black),
                          )
                              : IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                            tooltip: 'Refresh',
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await loadWeather();
                            },
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  //FUTURE FORECAST WEATHER DATA
                  SafeArea(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 200.0,
                        child: forecastData != null
                            ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: forecastData.list.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => WeatherItem(
                                weather: forecastData.list.elementAt(index)))
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ])),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't want to change the code. I just want to change the location of this code, but I don't know where to type it. I tried the code you thrown but it didn't work.

Comment: `//BACKGROUND IMAGE
Container(
              height: 501.7,
              width: 420.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: isweatherDataLoaded //this
                      ? HandleError()
                      : images["clear"],
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
            ),`

Comment: I have updated my answer with your code, just make the container with the background image the body property, and the rest of your code (starting with the Center Widget) should be a child of this container. Let me know if you run into any problems doing so.

Comment: It says " `Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.` " on Container parentheses. And says " `Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.` " on Center. What would you suggest I do to solve these errors?

Comment: I copied your complete code and tested it with Android Studio and don't get these errors. Try copying my code, I edited my original answer.

Comment: IT WORKS! THANKS!